# Flower lei from California to Japan

Tags: japanese-citizens

Will I be able to take a flower lei from San Francisco to Japan?  Is it allowed in my luggage?  Or do I have to hand carry it?  Is there a cost to take it on the plane?
How would I check it through agriculture check?